# The array indexes arent correctly accessed within my code, also the iteration within while loop is wrong

Tags: java

Currently I am working on the code in Java where each Player has a Rack object, and a method where I am encoutering a bug is a methos swap() , which should delete Fields(enumeration) from the requested indexes in the rack, and replace it with a random Field instead.
I attach all the code with irrelevant code deleted:
I have created a separate class called question where I have copied the buggy method called swap()

```
public class Question {
    
    
    private Player player;
    
    
    Question(Player p){
        player=p;
    }
    
    LetterBag lb = new LetterBag();
    
    public LetterBag getLetterBag() {
        return lb;
    }
    
    public void swap(Player p) {
        System.out.println("Your rack is "+p.getRack().getRack().toString());
        System.out.println("Please input which indexes of tiles you want to change, and separate them by a space please");
        String input = TextIO.getln();
        String[] indexes;
        indexes = input.split(" ");
        ArrayList<Integer> id = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String s : indexes) {
            id.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
        }
        //until here works, id has all the indexes correctly passed
        
        System.out.println("the size of the array is "+p.getRack().getRack().size());
        for(int i=0;i<p.getRack().getRack().size();i++) {
            System.out.println("the current index is " +i);
            System.out.println( "the current rack field is"+p.getRack().getRack().get(i));
        }
        //correctly goes through the rack before this
        
        for (Integer i : id) {
            
            System.out.println(i);
            
            System.out.println(p.getRack().getRack().get(i));
            Field temporary = p.getRack().getRack().get(i); //???? wrong here!
            p.getRack().getRack().remove(temporary);
            System.out.println("Here we removed the requested fields in the rack,the rack is:");
            System.out.println(p.getRack().getRack().toString());
        }
        System.out.println("after this here is a while loop to put elements back");
        System.out.println("here is the rack size now "+ p.getRack().getRack().size());
        while (p.getRack().getRack().size() < 7 ) {
            System.out.println("we get to this part of the code");
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                System.out.println("We get here as well");
                   Field tp = this.getLetterBag().getRandom();
                    p.getRack().getRack().add(tp);
                    System.out.println("The length of the bag of letters is "+getLetterBag().getBagOfLetters().size());
                    this.getLetterBag().getBagOfLetters().remove(tp);
                    System.out.println("The length of the bag of letters is after remove "+getLetterBag().getBagOfLetters().size());
                }
            }

    }
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Player player = new Player();
    Question q = new Question(player);
    q.swap(player);
    
    
}
```

There is a lot of prints in order to track where the problem occurs.
When I start to iterate through the integers in the id array, it prints the correct indexes but accesses the wrong fields from the rack.
In addition, later in the While loop, it iterates about 6 times, while it should only until the rack is of size 7.

I will add all other relevant classes with minimum relevant info:

```
public enum Field {
    
    STAR,TW,DW,TL,DL,EMPTY,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,BLANK;

}
```

enumeration which is used in the rack,

```
    public class LetterBag {

        private ArrayList<Field> bagOfLetters;
        private Random random = new Random();

//      private ArrayList<Field> rack;

        private Field[] bw = { Field.A, Field.A, Field.A, Field.A, Field.A, Field.A, Field.A, Field.A, Field.A, Field.A,
                Field.B, Field.B, Field.C, Field.C, Field.D, Field.D, Field.D, Field.D, Field.E, Field.E, Field.E, Field.E,
                Field.E, Field.E, Field.E, Field.E, Field.E, Field.E, Field.E, Field.E, Field.F, Field.F, Field.G, Field.G,
                Field.H, Field.H, Field.I, Field.I, Field.I, Field.I, Field.I, Field.I, Field.I, Field.I, Field.J, Field.J,
                Field.K, Field.K, Field.L, Field.L, Field.L, Field.L, Field.M, Field.M, Field.N, Field.N, Field.N, Field.N,
                Field.N, Field.N, Field.O, Field.O, Field.O, Field.O, Field.O, Field.O, Field.O, Field.O, Field.P, Field.P,
                Field.Q, Field.R, Field.R, Field.R, Field.R, Field.R, Field.R, Field.S, Field.S, Field.S, Field.S, Field.T,
                Field.T, Field.T, Field.T, Field.T, Field.T, Field.U, Field.U, Field.U, Field.U, Field.V, Field.V, Field.W,
                Field.W, Field.X, Field.Y, Field.Y, Field.Z, Field.Z, Field.BLANK, Field.BLANK };

        public LetterBag() {

            bagOfLetters = new ArrayList<Field>();
            for (int i = 0; i < bw.length; i++) {
                bagOfLetters.add(bw[i]);
            }

        }


        public ArrayList<Field> reset(){
            bagOfLetters = new ArrayList<Field>();
            for (int i = 0; i < bw.length; i++) {
                bagOfLetters.add(bw[i]);
            }
            return bagOfLetters;
        }
        
        public ArrayList<Field> getBagOfLetters() {
            return bagOfLetters;
        }
        
        public Field getRandom() {
            return this.getBagOfLetters().get(random.nextInt(this.getBagOfLetters().size()));
            
        }


}
```

this is the bag from where I access new Fields when I remove and add new one in the swap() method.

```
public class Player {

    private Rack rack;
    // -- Constructors -----------------------------------------------

    public Player() {
        this.rack = new Rack();
    }


    public Rack getRack() {
        return this.rack;
    }


}
```

```
public class Rack {
        
        private ArrayList<Field> rack;
        /*
         *a new bag of letters is initialized to create a rack since it is not said in the rules 
         * that a rack should be initialized from the general one.
         * Later the general one is used to progress with the game, the one both players use to derive the new tiles.
         */
        private LetterBag lb = new LetterBag(); 
        
        public Rack() {
            rack = new ArrayList<Field>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                Field tp = lb.getRandom();
                    rack.add(tp);
                    
                }
            }
        
        public ArrayList<Field> getRack() {
            return rack;

        }
}
```

and a rack itself.

It does iterate through it before in the swap() method correctly as is commented in the method.
Why could this happed?
Can it be because it iterates throgh Integer not int? However it should not be a problem as much as i am aware.
I will also attach the output of the console:

```
You rack is :[L, E, A, U, V, W, O]
Please input which indexes of tiles you want to change, and separate them by a space please
1 2 3
the size of the array is 7
the current index is 0
the current rack field isL
the current index is 1
the current rack field isE
the current index is 2
the current rack field isA
the current index is 3
the current rack field isU
the current index is 4
the current rack field isV
the current index is 5
the current rack field isW
the current index is 6
the current rack field isO
1
E
Here we removed the requested fields in the rack,the rack is:
[L, A, U, V, W, O]
2
U
Here we removed the requested fields in the rack,the rack is:
[L, A, V, W, O]
3
W
Here we removed the requested fields in the rack,the rack is:
[L, A, V, O]
after this here is a while loop to put elements back
here is the rack size now 4
we get to this part of the code
We get here as well
The length of the bag of letters is 102
The length of the bag of letters is after remove 101
We get here as well
The length of the bag of letters is 101
The length of the bag of letters is after remove 100
We get here as well
The length of the bag of letters is 100
The length of the bag of letters is after remove 99
We get here as well
The length of the bag of letters is 99
The length of the bag of letters is after remove 98
We get here as well
The length of the bag of letters is 98
The length of the bag of letters is after remove 97
We get here as well
The length of the bag of letters is 97
The length of the bag of letters is after remove 96
We get here as well
The length of the bag of letters is 96
The length of the bag of letters is after remove 95
```

Comment: is it the player can have only 7 items in the rack ? 
In the question class, please include the setting of the player before calling the swap so that people can copy to their ides and assist you

Comment: Yes Player has a Rack which always has a 7 items(Fields) inside.

Comment: just did a small adjustment so you could run the main of the class Question to see. In my original project the method swap() is in the class named Game, just pointing out for logical pattern, doesnt make difference for a bugg

Comment: i can't see the changes in the Question class.

Comment: I added main and Player object now you can literally use main to see how it works